# MySQL: Retrieve Values and Counts For Each

Tags: mysql

How can I count the occurrence of the field/column in SQL?

Example dataset:

```
A
A
A
A
B
B
C
```

I want:

```
A  |  4
A  |  4
A  |  4
A  |  4
B  |  2
B  |  2
C  |  1
```

Is there anyway to do it without using **GROUP BY**? So far all answer I get my query retuns the following:

```
A  |  4
B  |  2
C  |  1
```

Comment: With `COUNT` of course.

Comment: (Count) count everything. I want it for each value. It works when I use it with GROUP BY, but I want to show the total of each value.

Comment: it retuns: A | 4   B | 2   C | 1. This is not wat I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a nested sub-select for this desired result set.
If the example table name is `my_table` and the column called `col1`:

```
select col1,
    (select count(*) from my_table where col1 = t.col1) as Count
from my_table t;
```

Or if you want to remove the duplicates, use the `distinct` statement. It removes the duplicates of your result set.

```
select distinct col1,
    (select count(*) from my_table where col1 = t.col1) as Count
from my_table t;
```

Comment: but remember, sub-query will down your performance as Your table grows

Comment: @SofyanThayf Yes, that's true, but I don't think, you can achieve the desired result set in any other way.

Comment: No, I don't. I think that is the only way if @SunZ insist to do with SQL query. But the database is only back-end support, we can do many ways to get the expected format as result at the front-end programming (e.g. PHP)

Comment: @SofyanThayf I agree, but the question is only tagged with `mysql`, so I don't know, what language the result is interpreted in. Without that, or a more refined question, we can't provide a more suitable answer. But I totally agree, this isn't an elegant answer, but the best I could do, with the data provided.

Answer (score 2):

```
select value, count(*) from table group by value
```

Use HAVING to further reduce the results, e.g. only values that occur more than 3 times:

```
select value, count(*) from table group by value having count(*) > 3
```

Comment: Thanks Komalpreet, but it retuns:
A  |  4
B  |  2
C  |  1